# "dpkg -l" does not see any available package

Tags: dpkg

I don't understand why if I type `dpkg -l mutt`, I obtain no packages found matching mutt.

However mutt is there and can be installed by
    `sudo apt-get install mutt`

As far as I know `dpkg` (on debian) should list every package, installed or not, giving information on the package status.

Answer (score 6):

`dpkg -l` will list only the packages that are installed on your machine. In your case, the package `mutt` is not installed. To search for packages that are installed or not, you can use `aptitude search package-name-pattern`.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike **aptitude** or **apt-cache** with **dpkg** we can only list packages that are installed or were removed from our system.

To obtain information on a package that is or was not installed we may use

```
sudo apt-get update # to update the cache
apt-cache showpkg <packagename>
```

In case we only want to list a package that was not installed before we may issue

```
dpkg -l <packagename> || apt-cache showpkg <packagename>
```

Comment: really sure? so, why after installing exim4-base, dpkg -l exim* gives: `